# Google placed API : search restaurent by country or restaurent name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

i'm trying to get all the restaurant from UAE  like KFC against country name and restaurant name as mentioned below

```
 var url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?name=KFC&key=[my_key]&country=KSA&type=restaurant
```

This is what i get as respon

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>INVALID_REQUEST</status>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

how do i get list  of restaurants for specific country like UAE need your help please

Answer (score 0):

The `INVALID_REQUEST` in [Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) generally indicates that the request contains missing parameters. It will also be returned when attempting to add a place whose name is greater than 255 characters. Just double check your HTTP URL request.

Here's a sample Text Search HTTP URL request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/output?parameters
```

Output may be either JSON or XML and the required parameters are `query` and `key`
* `query` is a string on which to search, for example: "restaurant"
* `key` is your application [API key](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862)

The below example shows a search for restaurant near Sydney:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```